# Remap hotkey without losing native hotkey functionality

Tags: native, autohotkey, tilde

I want the keyboard shortcut <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> to perform two functions:

1. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (its normal function, e.g., to switch tabs in a web browser)
2. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> (which can be used to switch between Microsoft Word documents, for example)

It doesn't need to be context-sensitive, i.e., it's okay to send both commands regardless of what program(s) I am using. The closest I have come is the following:

~^Tab::^F6

which performs both of the desired functions, but a "Tab" keystroke is also sent along with the hotkey. (This would wreak havoc on my Word documents!) I need to preserve the native <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> functionality without sending a Tab keystroke. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just send both commands:

```
$^Tab::
    Send, ^{F6}
    sleep,50
    Send, ^{Tab}
return
```

Just note that some programs might not like that.

Comment: I see, I tried that but got the syntax wrong on ^{F6}. As you can see, I am a beginner. Thanks for your help!